# Trouble Passing Array Values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a sub that fills an array with a list of user defined values from a fixed range in my spreadsheet. I want to call this sub from another, and utilize the values in the array to drive a For Each loop.

When I call the sub `getInvoiceList` I can see that it does fill the array `invoiceList` with the user's values. But they don't pass back into the sub I call from.

```
Public Sub columnLoop()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    getInvoiceList
    Stop 'to view array values

    Sheets("Calculator").Columns(10).Font.Color = vbBlack

    For i = 0 To UBound(invoiceList)

    'Loops through column for specific value(as declared)
    'Recolors text when current cell value = specific value
        For j = 3 To Range("NumFilledRows").Value
            If Sheets("Calculator").Cells(j, 10).Value = invoiceList(i) Then
            Sheets("Calculator").Cells(j, 10).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub

'Fill array from fixed range
Public Sub getInvoiceList()
    Dim invoiceList() As Variant
    invoiceList = Sheet2.Range("C4:C14")

    Stop 'allows review of array.
End Sub
```

When I call the sub 'getInvoiceList' I can see that it does fill the array invoiceList with the user's values. But they don't pass back into the sub I call from.

`Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch`
     Debug takes me to the `For i = 0 to UBound` line.
     Locals window shows `invoiceList` but has `value = empty` both on Stop line and after clicking debug.

Comment: I see that you reformatted the references to my code; but how did you do that, so I know for next time?

Comment: Subs don't return anything. You could return from a Function or alternately you could move `Dim invoiceList() As Variant` outside of the Sub so it's accessible by everything in the module.

Comment: If you click the _Edited 5 mins ago_ link, you can see what characters were added for formatting.

Comment: Select code and press Ctrl + K for *Bloc**k***. Your array is a local variable. Either make it a function that returns an array, or declare the array in main sub and pass it to the sub to fill in.

Comment: @Mark Balhoff,  @ Noodles: Thank you. Moving the array declaration out side of the sub does work to pass the array values. Doing so then yields an Out of Range error at If Sheets("Calculator").Cells(j, 10).Value = InvoiceList(i) Then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables in/out of sub's.

```
Public Sub columnLoop()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, InvoiceList As Variant
    getInvoiceList  InvoiceList
    Stop 'to view array values

    Sheets("Calculator").Columns(10).Font.Color = vbBlack

    For i = 0 To UBound(InvoiceList)

    'Loops through column for specific value(as declared)
    'Recolors text when current cell value = specific value
        For j = 3 To Range("NumFilledRows").Value
            If Sheets("Calculator").Cells(j, 10).Value = InvoiceList(i) Then
            Sheets("Calculator").Cells(j, 10).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub

'Fill array from fixed range
Public Sub getInvoiceList(ByRef InvoiceList As Variant)

    InvoiceList = Application.Transpose(Sheet2.Range("C4:C14").Value)

    Stop 'allows review of array.
End Sub
```

Comment: I've read in my reference guide that this solution should work. But it does not: Runtime Error 13 Type Mismatch. Debugs to For i = 0.

Comment: @SFC9104 the type mismatch is due to the superfluous parentheses in the `getInvoiceList (InvoiceList)` call, which are attempting to pass the variant array by value, which isn't legal. Just drop the parens and it should work fine... after transposing the 2D variant array you're getting from `Sheet2.Range("C4:C14")` - i.e. do `InvoiceList = Application.Transpose(Sheet2.Range("C4:C14"))` and you'll get a one-dimensional variant array, which `UBound` will happily work with (a 2D array would require a dimension index for `UBound` to work).

Comment: Ah, I totally missed the Application.Transpose(Sheet2.Range("C4:C14")) update. HUZZAH! I had to update i= 0 to i =1 to resolve the out of range error; but I got colors now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to use a collection. Try my code below.

```
Public Sub columnLoop()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim coll As New Collection

    'add items to collection
    For Each cell In Sheets(2).Range("C4:C14")
        coll.Add cell
    Next
    Stop 'to view array values

    Sheets("Calculator").Columns(10).Font.Color = vbBlack

    Dim itm As Variant

    For Each itm In coll
        'Loops through column for specific value(as declared)
        'Recolors text when current cell value = specific value
        For j = 3 To Range("NumFilledRows").Value
            If Sheets("Calculator").Cells(j, 10).Value = itm Then 'checks values against items in collection
                Sheets("Calculator").Cells(j, 10).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next j
    Next itm

End Sub
```

Comment: Testing... Meanwhile, what are the benefits to using Collection instead of Arrays? If I expand this to search many more entries would it be lower/faster?

Comment: Collections are more dynamic.
See the differences here: https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/

Comment: `As New` makes `coll` an auto-instantiated object variable, which can have unintended consequences. Iterating object collections by index is also the single least efficient way to use collections, which are optimized for `For Each` iteration.

Comment: @W-hit This sort of worked. It doesn't throw any errors in the compiler; but it also doesn't seem to load values to the collection or evaluate true in any case. And yes, there are values to load from that range.

Comment: Is Sheet2 a public declaration, or is it actually the 2nd sheet? You may need to change the for each line to Sheet2.Range... if Sheet2 is already decalred

Comment: Sheet2 is the actual 2nd sheet.

Comment: edited my code, although I don't know if it will work for you now because I don't understand why it wasn't working in the first place